# Yahoo Finance API. Get company name from stock symbol without loading the entire YFinance module

Tags: python, python-requests, yahoo-finance

I would like to use either the python request module or the urllib module to get the company name by passing the stock symbol to the Yahoo Finance API. I don't want to use the YFinance Module because I don't need Panda's, Numpy, etc. I am trying to keep the size of my program down.

Here is the endpoint from the YFinance wrapper module:

```
name = yf.Ticker(symbol).info['shortName']
```

I'm just not sure how to make the request without the module.

Comment: There is a short name in the response to this.equest.`https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search?q=AAPL`

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks. That is just what i needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the endpoint from @r-beginners comment, I created a simple function using the `urllib` module to retrieve the company name from Yahoo Finance in Python. No `YFinance` module is needed. I hope this is helpful to someone else.

```
def get_yahoo_shortname(symbol):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(f'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search?q={symbol}')
    content = response.read()
    data = json.loads(content.decode('utf8'))['quotes'][0]['shortname']
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   import yfinance as yf

   ticker = "AAPL"
   stock_name = yf.Ticker(ticker).info["longName"]

   print(stock_name)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?